# Comparing two hashmaps in java and showing the values

Tags: java, compare, equals

I would like to compare 2 hashmaps and if the values ​​are the same, list these values ​​along with the key. How can I do it, because the function `equals()` returns true or false :/

Thanks in advance for your help :D

The code below is unfortunately not working, why?

```
for (String  s1 : MAP1.keySet()) 
    {
    for (String  s2 : MAP2.keySet()) 
    {
      if (MAP_SAP.get(s1).equals(MAP2.get(s2))) 
        {
         MAP3.put(key,value); // I believe that it has to be added otherwise

     
            }
        }
 }
  print("eee:");
   for (Map.Entry entry : MAP3.entrySet())
 {
     
  System.out.println("Numer: " + entry.getValue() + ", ID: " + entry.getKey() );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The most naive way would be to iterate over the values of the first map and check if there is an equal value in the second map.

Considering the two maps store keys and values of type String, the code looks something like this.

```java
for (String s1 : map1.keySet()) {
  for (String s2 : map2.keySet()) {
    if (map1.get(s1).equals(map2.get(s2))) {
      // print or do whatever with keys & the value
      // also, if you just need ONE match, then break out of inner loop here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to throw it into the map then map3.put ("what variables to give as key and value") ??

Comment: @pawlixo If you want to add the key and value to another map, use `map3.put(key, value)`.

Comment: Notice, that I have made a change to the code to iterate over the maps' keySets as you need to reference the key as well.

Comment: It doesn't have to be some assigned variables or something, not just a key and a value?

Comment: see below for the code

Comment: You have just hardcoded key and value which is going to result in an error unless they have been declared. Instead try `map3.put(s1, map1.get(s1))`.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to store both values in MAP3. I then wonder which key you want to use. From your words, I assume that if the value of s1 and s2 are equal, then the keys s1 and s2 are equal, too. Otherwise, it would make no sense that a pair of values from map1 and map2 has "a key".
Furthermore, you mention a fourth map MAP_SAP in the if-statement. I guess you mean MAP1, otherwise you have to make sure that MAP_SAP really contains the key s1 you got from MAP1.

```
//initialize MAP3 before starting the loops

for (String  s1 : MAP1.keySet()){
    for (String  s2 : MAP2.keySet()) {

      if (MAP1.get(s1).equals(MAP2.get(s2))){

         String key = s1; //or another key e.g. s1+s2
         String value = MAP1.get(s1);

         MAP3.put(key, value);
      }
    }
}

print("eee:");
for (Map.Entry entry : MAP3.entrySet()){
     System.out.println("Number: " + entry.getValue() + ", ID: " + entry.getKey() );
}
//alternatively you can use 
// MAP3.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("Number: " + value + ", ID: " + key));
´´´
```